# How to display promo banner in mobile website based on APP availability?

Tags: php, mobile, web

I need to display different banner in mobile website based on APP availability.

So how can i get the specific APP already installed or not from the mobile website.

Any one suggest me/guide me on this. Mobile website build by PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below method to check application is install or not.

public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

then check,

if(isAppInstalled(context,package)==true){

     // here display different banner.

}else {

}
```

Comment: Hi Virat, Thank you for your answer. but i need to check in PHP or javascript because this is PHP website.